# How to safely get down in Rise of the Tomb Raider?

Tags: macos, rise-of-the-tomb-raider

How can I get Lara swing from a height and let herself slowly go down to reduce the damage of falling? If you played Prince of Persia 1 you could remember this move. [Here](https://ibb.co/wsYj3WC) is a screenshot to show you what I mean.

Let alone doing this move, I even cannot use go forward button at the edge of a height. It seems jumping is the only way to get down and it is exactly the opposite of safe descending and totally irrational.

If this move is not available, what is the safest way to get down in such situations?

I am playing on a Mac.

[image: sample screenshot]

Comment: I haven't played Rise for a good while but if I remember correctly it is similar to Shadow and whenever there is an "unreachable" place there is usually a path to get down there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is right after you have collected the 'Ancient Abilities' Hunter skill, allowing you to rapidly fire two arrows after one another. You then arrived here by climbing up the Ice Ship as seen in the screenshot you posted. **You don't need to go down there again, but you need to head left**. There is a cable right there leading you to a different path.

See this video:

---

For the default keys to **drop safely from a ledge**, use <kbd>c</kbd> to drop, and <kbd>e</kbd> to grab on to the ledge.
Of course, this doesn't work in situations where you're not supposed to climb down.

Comment: Thanks, I already passed that point by simply jumping down, however your answer might be useful for other users. My question was about a general move.

Comment: Got you. Updated.